# Spring Boot error when I use a properties value inside an enum

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, properties

I have a Spring Boot project and I am trying to recovery a value of a .properties file and use it inside an enum.

I follow the next steps.

- I have a file `application.properties` with a `value = 000`. I recovery this value with:

  ```
  @RestController
  public class ReadProperty {

      @Value("${value}")
      public String value;

      public String getValueProperty() {
          return this.value;
      }

      @GetMapping(value = "/get")
      public String getValue() {
          System.out.println("read value is " + value);
          return value;
      }

      @GetMapping(value = "/getEnum")
      public String getValueEnum() {

          String response = EnumInsideAClass.TEST.toString();

          System.out.println("response value is " + response);
          return response;
      }
  }
  ```

If I use value in a class I get the value 000 without any problem.

- I create an enum inside a class like this

  ```
  public class EnumTest {

      @Autowired
      static ReadProperty readProperty;

      public final static String VAL = readProperty.getValueProperty();

      public enum EnumInsideAClass {

          TEST(VAL);

          private String value;

          private EnumInsideAClass(String value) {
              this.value = value;
          }

          @Override
          public String toString() {
              return this.value;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

The problem is that inside the enum class I need a static variable. If I use

```
@Value("${value}")
public static String value;
```

The value change to null.

So I tried to use access the value by a get method but the value is still null.

I am out of ideas, what can I do? Is posible use a propertie value inside an enum?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're describing has nothing to do with the `@Value` being in the `enum` but rather it has to do with your attempt to inject the property's value on a static variable.

Spring will let you inject values directly on **non-static** and **not** on static fields. If you want to do this in your case, you could potentially proxy the injection through a setter method e.g:

```
public static String value;

@Value("${value}")
public void setValue(String someValue) {
    SomeClass.value = someValue;
}
```

But I would advise you to be very aware of what you're doing. Since this is going to be a **non-final field** that is also **public** and **static** you need to be aware of who's allowed to access it and also who's allowed to change it's value.

Comment: To add, I don't see why you they could not just have a normal enum mapped to the properties. Rather than doing this maddness.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe, very true indeed. I'm just giving him the answer to his problem. Also, for me the whole `@Value` injection, while handy in some cases, is a bad idea. You end up with a myriad of properties scattered around a project without a common grouping place. That's why I prefer to have a properties service that uses `@ConfigurationProperties` to group them together. This way I just inject it whenever needed.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! I have reconsidered take out the field of the enum an use it directly from the properties. And recovery the properties via @ConfigurationProperties